# Who calls the getView() method of custom ArrayAdapter class

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

While using custom `ArrayAdapter` in android, the `getView()` of the custom **ArrayAdapter** is called by whom? I have searched this question a number of times... found it in StackOverflow but the answer which has been marked as satisfactory by the user is:

> for the developer it is not necessary to know that who calls the
>   `getView()` of the **ArrayAdapter** class".

Please, I humbly request that a more meaningful answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getView()` is called by a subclass of `AdapterView`. So, if you attach the `Adapter` to a `ListView`, `ListView` inherits from `AbsListView`, and [`AbsListView` will be calling `getView()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-8.0_r4/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L2342-L2407) to get the rows to display in the list.

Comment: that's what I heard in the couple of tutorials but is this thing implemented internally...as I can't see any snippet  calling the getView() of the ArrayAdapter class

Comment: @SumitPrasad: I updated my answer for greater clarity and with a link to one place where `getView()` gets called.